# Testing for bool values with generic T

Tags: c#, generics

I have a generic method which I'd like to pass in either a reference type or bool.

```
private void Test<T>(T value)
{
    if(typeof(T)) == typeof(bool))
    {
        if(value == false)
            // do something
        else if (value == null)
            // do something else
    }
}
```

but I'm getting this compile time error "Operator `==' cannot be applied to operands of type`T' and `bool'". Is there a simple solution to this (preferably without using Reflection)?

Update: If it's enclosed in a foreach loop, will there be an implicit cast? I still receive the same compile error.

```
private void Test<T>(T[] values)
{
    foreach(T value in values)
    {
        if(typeof(T)) == typeof(bool))
        {
            if(value == false)
                // do something
        }
        else if (value == null)
                // do something else
    }
}
```

Comment: T is a type argument and can be a class or a struct, Thus compiler won't let you perform actions that doesn't exist in classes and structs. (Side note: `value == false` -> `!value`)

Comment: I would be more inclined to ask why you need to do this? Something is wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need an ugly double cast, like this:

```
private void Test<T>(T value)
{
    if(typeof(T) == typeof(bool))
    {
        if((bool)(object)value)
            // do something
        else if (!(bool)(object)value)
            // do something else
    }
}
```

The same applies inside a loop:

```
private void Test<T>(T[] values)
{
    foreach(T value in values)
    {
        if(typeof(T) == typeof(bool))
        {
            if (!(bool)(object)value)
                // do something
        }
        else if (value == null)
                // do something else
    }
}
```

Although, this does a lot more comparisons than you need. This would be more efficient:

```
private void Test<T>(params T[] values)
{
    if(typeof(T) == typeof(bool))
    {
        foreach(bool b in values.Cast<bool>())
        {
            if (!b)
                // do something
        }
    }
    else
    {
        foreach(T value in values)
        {
            if (value == null)
            // do something else
        }
    }
}
```

Also not, if `do something` and `do something else` are the same, you can simplify this even more to:

```
private void Test<T>(params T[] values)
{
    foreach(T value in values)
    {
        if (value == default(T))
            // do something
    }
}
```

It should be noted, however, that testing for types inside a generic method, and using different strategies for different type arguments is pretty bad code-smell. You'd probably be better off providing a different overload for `bool` or any other parameter type you need to provide special handling for.

Comment: Thanks, but I get the following error with casting: "Cannot convert type `T' to `bool'"

Comment: @user2994682 Are us using the latest version of my code (with the double cast--`(bool)(object)value`)? you shouldn't see that error.

Answer (score 6):

Use the `is` operator:

```
private void Test<T>(T value)
{
    if(value is bool)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

or the `as` operator:

```
private void Test<T>(T value)
{
    bool? boolValue = value as bool;
    if (boolValue != null) {
        // do something with boolValue, which can never be null if value is of type bool
    }
    else {
        // do something with value, which is not a boolean
    }
}
```

Comment: Good point, but doesn't solve the problem to which OP is referring.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, updated to include `as` operator variation that will solve the issue of doing something with the value.

Comment: @mayabelle *The as operator must be used with a reference type or nullable type ('bool' is a non-nullable value type)*

Comment: Thanks, tho I'm getting an error "The `as' operator cannot be used with a non-nullable value type `bool'" using as.

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo and missed the question mark, it should be `bool?` which is nullable.

Comment: thanks for the answer, unfortunately I don't have enough rep to upvote but when I do I will!

Answer (score 2):

You still need to cast even if you've verified the type, and your `else` statement will never fire:

```
private void Test<T>(T value)
{
    if(typeof(T)) == typeof(bool))
    {
        if((bool)value == false)
            // do something
        else if (value == null) // this will never be true for a bool!
            // do something else
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how you are calling this method, you could just create an overload taking a `bool`:

```
private void Test(bool b)
{
    if(! b)
    {
        //do something
    }
}

private void Test<T>(T value) where T : class
{
    if(value == null)
    {
        //do something else
    }
}
```